# How do you hide parameters in custom build steps in Kotlin for TeamCity?

Tags: configuration, teamcity, kotlin, dsl

I'm trying to setup TeamCity, using config as code with Kotlin. I'm writing wrappers for buildsteps so I can hide the default exposed configuration and only expose parameters that matter. This would allow me to prevent users of the class from changing values that would cause build errors.

I want this:

```
steps {
    step {
        name = "Restore NuGet Packages"
        type = "jb.nuget.installer"
        param("nuget.path", "%teamcity.tool.NuGet.CommandLine.3.3.0%")        
        param("nuget.updatePackages.mode", "sln")
        param("nuget.use.restore", "restore")
        param("sln.path", "path_to_solution") //parameter here
        param("toolPathSelector", "%teamcity.tool.NuGet.CommandLine.3.3.0%")
}
```

...to be this:

```
MyBuildSteps.buildstep1("path_to_solution")
```

Here's the function signature for step:

```
public final class BuildSteps {
    public final fun step(base: BuildStep?, init: BuildStep.() -> Unit ): Unit { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
class MyBuildSteps {
fun restoreNugetPackages(slnPath: String): kotlin.Unit {
    var step: BuildStep = BuildStep {
        name = "Restore NuGet Packages"
        type = "jb.nuget.installer"
    }

    var stepParams: List = Parametrized {
        param("build-file-path", slnPath)
        param("msbuild_version", "14.0")
        param("octopus_octopack_package_version", "1.0.0.%build.number%")
        param("octopus_run_octopack", "true")
        param("run-platform", "x86")
        param("toolsVersion", "14.0")
        param("vs.version", "vs2015")
    }

    return {
        step.name
        step.type
        stepParams
    } //how do I return this?
  }
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: What class does `step` belong to?

Comment: Hi voddan, it belongs to
     public final class BuildSteps {

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question and my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to encapsulate `step {...}` into a function `buildstep1` with a parameter `slnPath`.

Use this function signature and copy-paste the `step {...}` part right inside. Add any parameters you see fit:

```
fun BuildSteps.buildstep1(slnPath: String) {
    step {
        name = "Restore NuGet Packages"
        type = "jb.nuget.installer"
        param("nuget.path", "%teamcity.tool.NuGet.CommandLine.3.3.0%")        
        param("nuget.updatePackages.mode", "sln")
        param("nuget.use.restore", "restore")
        param("sln.path", slnPath) // your parameter here
        param("toolPathSelector", "%teamcity.tool.NuGet.CommandLine.3.3.0%")
    }
}
```

That's all! Use it instead of the `step {...}` construct:

```
steps {
    buildstep1("path_to_solution")
}
```

This function may be declared anywhere in the configuration file (I usually place those at the bottom) or in a separate `.kts` file and imported (theoretically).

Comment: thank you so much voddan, this worked perfectly! kudos to your kotlin knowledge

Comment: I do have one more question, the "BuildSteps.buildstep1" syntax construct is new to me, what exactly is going on here?

Comment: This is something called an "extension function". It transfers the contexts from the call site into the function.

Comment: This is a fundamental feature of Kotlin, you can lean it from https://kotlinlang.org/. I did not include an explanation into the answer because learning how to make DSLs is 80% of all Kotlin. You'll be better of mastering the language than only DSL features.